# How to create a wifi hotspot from the command line?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, wireless, hot-spot, ap-hotspot

There are some good directions [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/) for how to create a wifi hotspot by confguring a connection using the gui with wifi hardware that supports AP mode. However, I need to be able to do it within  a script and am not certain how to go about do that. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

What is the best method?

Comment: are you using network-manager?

Comment: If you look at the instructions I provided a link to, I do not believe they use the network-manager. Do you have alternate instructions, which would be easier to implement on the command line?

Comment: The point of my question is: do you want to use network-manager or not? Or you don't care? I'm not a NM expert, but I think the method of creating a hotspot with NM is different from the method using hostapd

Comment: I probably don't care.

Comment: Try with this: https://nims11.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/hostapd-the-linux-way-to-create-virtual-wifi-access-point/ (sorry, I know I should write a proper answer, but I don't have enough time right now)

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out. I will probably end up using an answer that involves the default features of ubuntu, like NM. It does appear that NM has a command line client which I may be able to use to do what I need to do.